# How do I allow others to POST large data sets to my org and have it saved to an object?

Tags: apex, custom-object

Given a specific format, say:

```
{"employees":[
    {"firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe"},
    {"firstName":"Anna", "lastName":"Smith"},
    {"firstName":"Peter", "lastName":"Jones"}
]}
```

What code do I need to write in my org to other allows to POST to it and save it to something like an SObject?

Comment: You could create a public sites page and take the body of the post and do what you need to BUT this is a BAD idea as there would be no security around it. You should use RestResource to create a REST endpoint with authentication

Comment: See e.g. [Creating REST APIs using Apex REST](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Creating_REST_APIs_using_Apex_REST). [JSON2Apex](http://json2apex.herokuapp.com/) is handy for generating classes to match the JSON. Note that there is a 6M limit on the data that can be received so your calling code may need to break the data up into multiple requests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Frankly, it is a very open ended question.

A simple answer will be, that Salesforce provide SOAP/ REST services out of the box. So, you can create an sobject in your Salesforce org. and any client (who wants to send data to your org.) can utilize Salesforce SOAP/ REST services to push data into the newly created SObject.

Find more details at https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/

Further, you can also create your own SOAP/ REST web services, if you want to add some business logic to it. Get more details at:- https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Apex_Web_Services_and_Callouts

Bear in mind, that any client (requesor) needing to access your org. will need to get authenticated (mostly need a user account).

Answer (score 0):

You have to write a REST webservice in APEX & give its endpoint url to others, who would like to post data using this service.